# Generate BOD OAGIS XML from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, xml, schema

I need to generate an XML document from SQL Server that conforms to the [BOD OAGIS schema](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd277892(v=bts.10).aspx).

I have a partial solution but am not getting the exact format I need.

This is my query:

```
SELECT
(
  SELECT Customer As 'SalesOrderHeader/CustomerParty/ID',  
  (
    SELECT LinesNo As 'LineNumber'
      FROM LinesInterfaccia 
      WHERE HeaderInterfaccia.OrderNo = LinesInterfaccia.OrderNo  
      FOR XML path('salesline'), TYPE
  )
  FROM HeaderInterfaccia
  FOR XML path('salesorder'), type
).query('for $i in /salesorder return <DataArea>{$i}</DataArea>');
```

This is my result:

```
<DataArea>
  <salesorder>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
      <CustomerParty>
        <ID>BP00003184</ID>
      </CustomerParty>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
    <salesline>
      <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
    </salesline>
    <salesline>
      <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
    </salesline>
  </salesorder>
</DataArea>
<DataArea>
  <salesorder>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
      <CustomerParty>
        <ID>BP00003184</ID>
      </CustomerParty>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
    <salesline>
      <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
    </salesline>
  </salesorder>
</DataArea>
```

but I need this format:

```
<DataArea>
   <Process>tenant</Process>

  <salesorder>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
      <CustomerParty>
        <ID>BP00003184</ID>
      </CustomerParty>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
    <salesline>
      <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
    </salesline>
    <salesline>
      <LineNumber>20</LineNumber>
    </salesline>
  </salesorder>
</DataArea>
<DataArea>
    <Process>tenant</Process>
  <salesorder>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
      <CustomerParty>
        <ID>BP00003184</ID>
      </CustomerParty>
    </SalesOrderHeader>
    <salesline>
      <LineNumber>10</LineNumber>
    </salesline>
  </salesorder>
</DataArea>
```

I also tried:

```
SELECT  
(
  SELECT 'tenant' as 'Process',
    Customer As 'SalesOrderHeader/CustomerParty/ID',  
    (select LinesNo  as 'LineNumber/no'
```

with result:

```
<DataArea>
  <salesorder>
    <Process>tenant</Process>
    <SalesOrderHeader>
```

My expected structure is:

```
<DataArea>
   <Process>
   </Process>
     <SalesOrder>
        <SalesLine>
        </Salesline>
        <SalesLine>
        </Salesline>

     </salesOrder>
</DataArea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
DECLARE @tblOrder TABLE(OrderID INT IDENTITY, CustomerID VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @tblOrder VALUES('BP00003184')
                           ,('One More');

DECLARE @tblOrderLine TABLE(OrderLineID INT IDENTITY, OrderID INT, LineNumber INT);
INSERT INTO @tblOrderLine VALUES(1,10),(1,20)
                               ,(2,22),(2,33);

SELECT 'tenant' AS Process
      ,o.CustomerID AS [salesorder/SalesOrderHeader/CustomerParty/ID]
      ,(
        SELECT LineNumber
        FROM @tblOrderLine AS ol 
        WHERE ol.OrderID=o.OrderID
        FOR XML PATH('salesline'),TYPE
       ) AS salesorder
FROM @tblOrder AS o
FOR XML PATH('DataArea');
```

This structure is missing a root element, which is - by definition invalid XML. SQL Server has no problem with this, but other engines might have...

You can think of the process as such:

- Go down the columns of the select
- Oh, there's a new `XPath` (*Process*), let's open a new tag
- Oh, the next one is new, close `/Process`
- Uh, quite large (`salesorder/SalesOrderHeader/CustomerParty/ID`), open it!
- Ah, this is an XML itself. It will be called `salesorder`. Nice! **still open**!
- Good, I found the `FROM`, let's close the current `XPath`